# Swift - collection header view disappears when scrolls about 50% up?

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, collectionview

Ok, don't know what's happening here but I have a basic header view on my collection view, that is not sticky. When I scroll up and the header is hidden by top of the phone (about 50% hidden), the whole view disappears. I dont know whether this is a visibility or scale thing.

Made header view in storyboard with pretty basic settings then:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                        at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView: HeaderCollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView


        //header1 = headerView as! UICollectionReusableView

        return headerView
```

Its fine until scrolling, but I dont do anything with the scrolling functions. Whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I think it due to the constraint of tableview is wrong. Because the header view will follow the constraints of tableview.

Comment: check both of them. Maybe top layout constraint not properly